# Performing batch conversion in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I've try to convert SHP files to geoJSON. When batch process is started occure problem. Here is copy flrom log:

```
Processing algorithm 1/233…
Algorithm Convert format starting…
Input parameters:
{'INPUT': 'sp gid_1', 'OPTIONS': '', 'OUTPUT': 'D:/test/1sp gid_1.geojson'}

GDAL command:
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" "\"D:/test/1sp gid_1.geojson\"" C:/Users/vimars/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_01832e3931f144a18ec42d0c69d8bdb5/fb63b857189c43f9b5180a5c6b4b80ed/INPUT.shp gid_1
GDAL command output:
ERROR 4: Failed to create GeoJSON datasource: "D:/test/1sp gid_1.geojson": 

ERROR 1: GeoJSON driver failed to create "D:/test/1sp gid_1.geojson"

Algorithm Convert format correctly executed…
Execution completed in 0.36 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': 'D:/test/1sp gid_1.geojson'}

Loading resulting layers
```

I've triple chech that d:\test have write permission but still no luck :( No file was created in destination folder.

Additional info: single task work with no problem:

```
Processing algorithm…
AlgorithmDialog
Input parameters:
{ 'INPUT' : 'D:\sp|layername=gid_1', 'OPTIONS' : '', 'OUTPUT' : 'D:/test/1.geojson' }

GDAL command:
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" "D:/test/1.geojson" C:/Users/vimars/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_01832e3931f144a18ec42d0c69d8bdb5/cd83614a8607490c9e6eb526af0c309c/INPUT.shp INPUT
GDAL command output:
Execution completed in 0.85 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':D:/test/1.geojson, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Convert format' finished
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour].  Please [Edit] the question to contain the relevant code, so we can tell you the exact error.

Comment: @vince kindly thanks. Can you explain what code I must provide in addition to error log? I don't write my own script just want to convert more  than 200 shape files to geojson format. I can provide screenshots later

Comment: Totally out of clear logic, i decide to try export file in same directory where shape file reside. And... all export task was successfull. Have no idea what is going on here...